# Minimal example to wrap a library component in angular12

Tags: html, angular

In developing an Angular app, I find myself using similar HTML components with the same arugments over and over.  For example:

```
<fa-icon class="tms-hover-animation px-2" (click)="onDeleteContact(row)"
          [icon]="faTrash" ngbTooltip="Delete Contact" placement="bottom auto" container="body">
```

The `placement` and `container` fields are redundantly defined over and over and over.  What I'd much rather be able to do is the following:

```
<my-fa-icon (click)="onDeleteContact(row)" [icon]="faTrash"></my-fa-icon>
```

However,I can't find an minimal example of how to do this.

To clarify: my main misunderstanding is how can I reuse `<fa-icon` and pass all of its inputs (click, icon, etc... ) without having to explicitly redeclare them in my wrapper?  Something like:

```
@Component
FaIconWrapper
   args:  <-- These automatically passed into underlying fa-icon
```

How could we create a custom HTML element like this with default arguments, but still pass `(click), [icon]` and any other inputs down into the wrapped component?

I'm also worried about falling into an anti-pattern here.

Comment: minimal example https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs

Comment: more on the subject https://levelup.gitconnected.com/data-passing-in-parent-and-child-component-with-angular-652e7fd43626

Comment: The `placement` and `container` comes from `ngbTooltip` and you can configure defaults for them by extending `NgbTooltipConfig`.  I am not use if question is akward or u meant something else...

Comment: I tried to update the question, but my main issue is how can I reuse `<fa-icon` without having to explicitly choose which @Inputs (like `[icon]`) it uses?  LIke if `<fa-icon` had 50 @Inputs, I don't want to have to explicitly know about them in my wrapper.

Comment: If you want to create an angular library, try to start off creating an [NX workspace](https://nx.dev). [Here are the instructions I followed](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/commands.txt) creating my libraries. It includes a github action which builds tests and pushes the package if built from the master branch